# Hibernate and multiple OneToOne without creating new columns

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have the following situations with multiple OneToOne reletanships:

```
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "settingColumnName")
    private Settings setting;
}

@Table(name = "Account")
public class Account {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "settingColumnName")
    private Settings setting;
}

@Table(name = "Settings")
public class Settings{
    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "userColumnName")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "accountColumnName")
    private Account account;
}
```

Now, the issue here is that I have to create and save each model independently, because they are created as a result of StreamEvent capturing. Also, Hibernate will create automatically `userColumnName` and `accountColumnName`. What I would really need to do is to have something this:

[image]

Is this possible to implement with Hibernate? Could someone provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
@JoinColumn(name="userColumnName", insertable=false,updatable=false),

@JoinColumn(name="accountColumnName", insertable=false,updatable=false),
```

And Add two more fields in  Settings Entity for these tow column and Map with same Column